IBM DB2 SQL SUM Prior year same day data of subquery
I am trying to SUM prior year data from a subquery (MATRIX). Basically...here's what I tried but it produces the same data as the current data (incorrect).
SELECT
    SUM(MATRIX.TOTALH)
    OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY
            YEAR(MATRIX.DATE) - 1,
            MONTH(MATRIX.DATE),
            DAY(MATRIX.DATE)
    )
    AS TOTALH_PY
FROM
(
) MATRIX

What is the issue with this?
I tried using SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY) with the year being YEAR(<date>) - 1 but this did not work. I was expecting it to produce the SUM for the same day over the prior year.

You probably need to use LAG() but it's not clear from the question. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

What Db2 platform are you using? LUW, iSeries, z/OS?

Please note that the PARTITION BY clause is not a filter. Use a WHERE condition to filter the last year.

Can you try:
SELECT
    SUM(M.TOTALH) as TOTALH_PY
FROM  MATRIX M
WHERE M.DATE 
     BETWEEN add_years(M.DATE date('001-01-01'), YEAR(SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) - 1)
             And 
             add_days((SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1), -DAYOFYEAR(SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1))


Maybe try this (doesn't account for leap years):
SELECT SUM(MATRIX.TOTALH)
       OVER (PARTITION BY MATRIX.DATE
             ORDER BY DAYS(MATRIX.DATE) --convert date to a number, to allow to use "RANGE" clause
             RANGE BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND 365 PRECEDING --looking just at that one day "exactly" one year ago
            )
  FROM MATRIX

Naturally, rows from the year before (which You want to SUM) must be a part of all rows selected. Otherwise this OLAP function (SUM OVER) would not "find" them in the resultset.
